# Is webapp2 an abandoned project? is it soon to have an EOL(End Of Life)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I depend a lot on the [Webbapp2 Framework](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp2)  to build my web apps and find it to currently be   my easiest(favorite) alternative to others like Django & Flask because it integrates seamlessly with the python API for Google app engine.
I am however very worried of the fact that;

1. the twitter(@webapp2) last tweeted in 2011.
2. there is no active GitHub repo for webapp2 maintained by Google and yet [Google code is turning READ ONLY!.](https://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/ReadOnlyTransition)
3. no new release version since 2011!

Those three reasons above have led me to think that the Project is Abandoned and might be killed eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since webapp2 (just as its predecessor webapp) was designed primarily/specifically for the GAE Python sandbox I think it's safe to assume it (or a reasonably similar replacement, if any) will remain alive for as long as GAE Python sanbox will.

Should at some point Google will decide to retire or replace it I presume they will also, as usual, provide early official notifications and ample time for migration to an alternate suggested solution before the apps relying on it will stop working.

I'd interpret the lack of activity on its codebase simply a sign of the code's quality and maturity.

WRT the Google Code going read-only it's really just a step in discontinuing Google's service of hosting sw projects, it doesn't mean development of those projects stops altogether. Development will be migrated to better project hosting services: 
http://google-opensource.blogspot.ca/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html